# How To Correctly Send E-Mail From Localhost

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, php-ini, server-configuration

I'm trying to test out some email scripts form my localhost but it doesn't seem to be working for any of the smtp settings that I'm using.  I was able to activate it using the settings that I have from my business server but it has put a block on me for sending too many emails.  Here were the settings (edited):

```
[mail function]
    ; For Win32 only.
    SMTP = mail.mydomain.co.uk
    smtp_port = 26
    sendmail_from = info@mydomain.co.uk
```

Are there any other settings I can use that will successfully allow me to send emails via my localhost in the mail function, such as from google, etc, etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on a windows machine sending emails from a localhost via local smtp is rather hard, you can use libraries, I advise Swiftmailer, to send emails from your external email account, e.g. Gmail

Comment: Thank you, I've downloaded swiftmailer - Are there any tutorials on how to set it up properly?

Comment: Presumably this only works on localhost and needs to be edited/deleted when put on a live server?

Comment: on the swiftmailerpage itself is a good tutorial how to achieve this. And no, this also works on a live server. If your live server supports SMTP you can also send mails directly from your server with a few changes to your code

Comment: While I was searching for a tutorial I found one for something called sendmail and tried that - Got it to work in no time and it works well so I'm going to stick with using that for now - Thanks for the advice though, it's good to know there are a few alternatives around